# JAVA: ¿Es posible escribir dos veces la concatenación en una sola línea del código para imprimir en consola?

Tags: java, netbeans

Por ejemplo
Quiero que salga en el mensaje que diga Liga de Quito vs El Nacional.
Liga de Quito y Nacional son variables que se ingresa por el teclado

```
System.out.println("Equipo:"+equipo1, "Vs" +equipo2);
```

Algo así
Lo se que debo tener variables para concatenar solo quiero saber si se puede así?

Comment: puedes concatenar todas las veces que quieras siempre y cuando sean strings/char, y uses el + cada que cambias de texto entre comillas y una variable.

Comment: La linea de código que colocaste esta mal, ya que la coma que pusiste después de la variable equipo1 te generara un error ya que se encuentra fuera de las comillas. Lo siguiente es lo correcto: System.out.println("Equipo: " + equipo1  +”, Vs “ + equipo2); respeta los espacios dentro de las comillas para que tengas un mejor formato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para concatenar las dos variables debe ser de este modo

```
System.out.println("Equipo: " + equipo1 + " Vs " + equipo2);
```

Es decir la variable que va concatenada al centro del string va rodeada de dos signos de + y la última variable lleva la concatenación con el signo de + al inicio

Si lo dejas cómo está ahorita la variable equipo dará error pues se puede asumir como una cadena de texto que está fuera de las comillas

Comment: Muchas gracias solo toca eliminar esa coma y añadir un signo :)

Answer (score 0):

Si, debe hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
System.out.println("Equipo: " + equipo1 + " Vs " + equipo2);
```